# Can pull-down resistor be connected before the gate resistor?

Tags: mosfet, resistors, pulldown

I noticed I have made a mistake in one of my PCBs and have connected the pull-down resistor of a MOSFET before its gate resistor (point A), rather than to the gate directly (point B, see schematic) as I assume is the correct way.

I was wondering, if not given a high signal, voltage at point A would be 0 so would that also pull the gate low or is the gate resistor going to cause trouble?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK7aAl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That should be fine; the "extra" 100 ohms of pulldown resistance are less than the tolerance band of a 1% 20k resistor so no problem there.

Comment: This is actually the best way if you want maximum Gate drive voltage (not a significant difference in this case, but could be if R1 was a larger value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

100 ohms is 0.5% of 20k ohms.

It does not make a difference. Most likely you are not using 1% resistors, and even if you were, it would be off less than 2%.

Comment: I realized how dumb of a question I just asked, of course right after asking it. Effectively I'm just increasing the pull-down resistance by 100 ohms...